# set `all-the-icons-dired` to use consistent directory icon?

Tags: dired, images

I installed [all-the-icons-dired](https://github.com/jtbm37/all-the-icons-dired) package from melpa, however, it does not use consistent icons for directories. Some directories have their own special icon. Example, these are two directories:

[image: two directories]

The `.dartServer` icon above is a standard directory icon, however, `Desktop` uses a special icon.

I prefer the standard directory icon for *all* directories. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but perhaps you can edit the variable `all-the-icons-dir-icon-alist`.

For example, for Dropbox, you can see an entry like:

```
("dropbox" all-the-icons-faicon "dropbox" :height 1.0 :v-adjust -0.1)
```

and replace the 2nd "dropbox" with "folder" or "folder-o" (the latter is a kind of transparent looking folder icon.